# How to concatenate string and variable in django view.py?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-views

i want to concatenate string and variable in views.py file.

i tried {{}} but this is not working on views.py file.

```
    try:
         filename= file.cv #file name comes from db
         path = "media/" filename
         return FileResponse(open("path, 'rb'), content_type='application/pdf')
    except FileNotFoundError:
         raise Http404()
```

i need to save a string in path variable like "media/cv.pdf" or "media/mycv.pdf" but can't do that.

Comment: `path = "media/"  + filename` or `path = os.path.join("media",  filename)`

Comment: 2nd one is working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `filename` is a string so you could conacatenate like two strings

```
path = "media/" + filename
```

but preferred is

```
path = os.path.join("media", filename)
```

which will use `/` on Linux/MacOS and `\` on Windows

Comment: 1st one is not working fine and the second one is working fine.

Comment: all may depends what text you have in variable `filename` - if there is only filename without folders then they should generate the same string. you can always check it with `print( path )` and see if both gives the same. But as I wrote in answer second is preferred because it may do something more then only concatenate strings.